# How Pancakeswap calculates its fee on smart contract level?

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

If user calls the `swapExactETHForTokens` function of the [PancakeRouter contract](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/master/contracts/PancakeRouter.sol) it will recieve the amount values from the `getAmountsOut` function of the [PancakeLibrary contract](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/PancakeLibrary.sol).

`getAmountsOut` calls `getAmountOut` to calculate the available token amount based on the reserves of the liquidity pool. But `getAmountOut` calculates with a fee of `0.20%` as it uses `amountIn.mul(998)` here:

```
// given an input amount of an asset and pair reserves, returns the maximum output amount of the other asset
function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountOut) {
    require(amountIn > 0, 'PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
    require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
    uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(998);
    uint numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(reserveOut);
    uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(1000).add(amountInWithFee);
    amountOut = numerator / denominator;
}
```

However, at the end of the transaction in the low level `swap` function of the liquidity pool, the account balance is adjusted by `0.25%`. So what is happening here? Why `getAmountOut` uses `0.20%` and `swap` `0.25%` in the same chain of function calls if the fee is `0.25%`?

```
function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
    require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
    (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
    require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
    uint balance0;
    uint balance1;
    { // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
    address _token0 = token0;
    address _token1 = token1;
    require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, 'Pancake: INVALID_TO');
    if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (data.length > 0) IPancakeCallee(to).pancakeCall(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
    balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    }
    uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
    uint amount1In = balance1 > _reserve1 - amount1Out ? balance1 - (_reserve1 - amount1Out) : 0;
    require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
    { // scope for reserve{0,1}Adjusted, avoids stack too deep errors
    uint balance0Adjusted = (balance0.mul(10000).sub(amount0In.mul(25)));
    uint balance1Adjusted = (balance1.mul(10000).sub(amount1In.mul(25)));
    require(balance0Adjusted.mul(balance1Adjusted) >= uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1).mul(10000**2), 'Pancake: K');
    }

    _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
    emit Swap(msg.sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to);
}
```

Comment: Refer to the [Uniswap V2 whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper.pdf).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg it helps a bit, but Pancakeswap calculates with two different values, while Biswap for instance uses the same 0.1%. There should be a specific reason why they use 0.2% and 0.25%.